# New column in dataframe with calculations from rows based on other column´s conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am trying to get  a new column ("Resilience" ) to my dataframe (df)  with the values from calculating : (Diversity in Flood - Diversity in Control )/ Diversity in Control
, for each different Plot.

This is my dataframe

```
df<-  data.frame(
  Plot = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  Rain =c("Control", "Flood", "Dry","Control", "Flood", "Dry","Control", "Flood", "Dry"), 
  Diversity = sample (1:10, 9)
)
```

I have tried to use dplyr package , with arrange, group_by and mutate and the ifelse functions, but I am stuck. I don´t know how to include the condition to substract the Diversity of the control treatment to the diversity of the flood treatment and then divide all by the diversity of the control again.

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Plot, Rain)%>%
  group_by(Plot)%>%
  mutate(Resilience=NA,
         Resilience = ifelse(Rain =="Flood", Diversity???, NA))
```

Maybe dplyr is not the way to do it?
Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are trying to calculate here. Can you please provide the desired output for the sample input so we can test and verify possible solutions?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick for your answer. I am trying to add the dataframe but sill gives me an error message and I cannot edit it, or do not reads well when I add it. Maybe you could let me know how to add the output right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `match` to get corresponding `Diversity` value for `"Control"` for each `Plot`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(dc = Diversity[match("Control", Rain)],
         Resilience = ifelse(Rain =="Flood",(Diversity - dc)/dc, NA), .by= Plot)

#  Plot    Rain Diversity dc Resilience
#1    A Control         6  6         NA
#2    A   Flood         4  6 -0.3333333
#3    A     Dry         8  6         NA
#4    B Control         7  7         NA
#5    B   Flood         5  7 -0.2857143
#6    B     Dry         1  7         NA
#7    C Control         9  9         NA
#8    C   Flood         3  9 -0.6666667
#9    C     Dry         2  9         NA
```

Note that the `.by` Syntax is available in `dplyr` 1.1.0 and above. Also I have created a temporary `dc` column so that we can reuse it twice without calculating it twice. You may remove the column if you don't need.

Comment: Thank you Ronak, your answer has helped me to solve my problem and learn more about dplyr :)